# Set editable=False only in subclass

Tags: python, django

I have a field "name" that is automatically constructed from "first_name" and "last_name" in one of the subclasses:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=60)

class Company(Actor):
    pass

class Person(Actor):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail address'), unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.first_name or self.last_name:
            self.name = (self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name).strip()
        else:
            self.name = self.email
        super(Person, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would like the "name" field to be editable in the Actor and Company models, but not in the Person model.  How can I accomplish that?

I can't override the field definition by adding

```
name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=60, editable=False)
```

to the Person model because Django raises a FieldError ("Local field 'name' in class 'Person' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'Actor'").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about `editable` and exclude the field in the model's ModelAdmin instead:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Person, exclude=['name'])
```